# Cannot connect docker app to kafka docker container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, dockerfile

I am trying to connect my Kafka container and my docker image all running locally
and don't want to create a container with Kafka and zookeeper images.

When I am running the app without dockerizing it, it is working fine.

After running the dockerize app the docker logs is showing

```
could not read message dial tcp 172.21.0.3:9092: i/o timeout
```

in Kafka logs, it is showing

```
kafka-zookeeper-1  | 2021-12-07 06:17:15,755 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-7:ZooKeeperServer@1411] - Connection request from old client /172.18.0.1:56350; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
```

this is the docker compose for kafka

```
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - /Users/myuser/docker/volumes/kafka:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

Can anyone help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the bitnami image readme section referring to external and internal clients. Also, if you're running the app in Docker, you should include it in this compose file

Answer (score 1):

> When I am running the app without dockerizing it, it is working fine.

Basically, you want your app to connect to Kafka in both cases right?

- when you're running your app locally (on the host machine)
- and when you're running it as a dockerized application.

But you're only advertising one listener for `127.0.0.1:9092` (the host machine) so even if a dockerized client (your app) can access Kafka container, it will still fail to establish a connection because of a misleading listener configuration.

For example, I can use this for advertising two different listeners for two different networks (docker network and localhost on the host machine):

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```

And when I run my dockerized application, it can connect to Kafka via `broker:29092` and, similarly, when I run the app on the host machine, it can connect to Kafka via `localhost:9092`.

[This post](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) gives a more detailed explanation of how Kafka advertised listeners work and how should we configure them. It basically says:

> You need to set advertised.listeners (or KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS if
> you’re using Docker images) to the external address (host/IP) so that
> clients can correctly connect to it. Otherwise they’ll try to connect
> to the internal host address–and if that’s not reachable then problems
> ensue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer,

- You must use host ip address. Do not use 127.0.0.1 or container ip address
- Because, the brokers are advertising its `ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` to their clients, and clients try to connect to this addresses.
- So, the ip addresses in the `ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` must accessible from outside container or other containers.
- Refer following example

```yaml
...
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://<hostip>:9092
...
```

Comment: So why does my app connect to the broker when not in dockerized container ?

Comment: Using the host ip isn't a "must". Using a resolvable address from wherever the clients are running is. Between containers this would be the service name, not a specific ip. Advertising localhost is fine assuming the app is not containerized **and** the Kafka listener port is forwarded

Comment: @RachitKawar, your question is wrong. The app only running in the same host can connect to brokers. Apps running on the other host cannot connect to the brokers who has  a advertised listeners as `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. If brokers are not dockerized, you can omit `advertised.listeners` config.